# Can I access a cursor from within a procedure by name?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

The cursor name would be passed in as a varchar2, and the cursor itself exists in the same package as the procedure.

Given only the name (and not a cursor reference) is it possible to access the cursor and loop through it?

If this requires the use of an "execute immediate" or similar, that's not out of the question... (though it's not quite clear to me how that would work, I was under the impression anything it declares is out of scope once it completes).

Apologies in advance, this seems like it should be obvious to me but I'm coming up blank.

Comment: passing in cursor by reference would simplify your question

Comment: The procedure will be run directly, not called by another procedure... and from another system that can only pass in strings.

Comment: Can the "other system" deal with ref cursors? If so, you could just take the string that is passed in and open the ref cursor for that, e.g. `open cur_var for p_sql_string`, and then pass the ref cursor back to the other system for it to loop round.

Comment: how about storing the cursor as a varchar2 in a table with bind variables? Then pass the Id of the cursor and open that in the procedure

Comment: The other system can't, or I wouldn't ask.

Comment: the only other way I can think you would do this is to pass the results back as a collection or set of collections - you might possibly need to invoke dbms_sql if you don't know which columns the front end is going to request. The front end can then loop through the collections.

Comment: You can dynamically execute also a valid PL/SQL code, not only a SQL, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6907617/272735. So this is a very possible. However because we don't know enough details it's impossible give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I'm having zero luck with execute immediate 'open ' || cursor_name || '(param1, param2)'; ... keeps choking with a ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement. I don't believe open is a valid statement to run with execute immediate. And open-for only takes a statement as a string, not an explicitly named cursor.

Comment: Do each of the cursors return a rowset with a similar "shape" - that is, same number of columns returned, with each column having the same datatype as the corresponding columns in the rowsets returned by the other cursors? Adding some examples to your question would be helpful.

Comment: @BobJarvis Each of the cursors will have the same record definition, and I'll hammer them into that shape if they don't. But they are explicitly named cursors, there are many of them, and defining them in the package as plain strings isn't really a good option.

Comment: @JohnO You didn't looked carefully enough the example I linked. PL/SQL code have to be encapsulated inside a PL/SQL block `begin ... end;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about this a bit, I think you're going about it the wrong way. I'd UNION ALL the results from each of the "cursors" together and then use the "cursor name" to eliminate all the unwanted rows (which the optimizer should optimize away) so that you only get the rows you want. So something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DO_SOMETHING(pin_Cursor_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  CURSOR csrFruits IS
    SELECT UPPER(pin_Cursor_name) AS FRUIT_TYPE,
           VARIETY_NAME,
           COLOR,
           SIZE,
           TARTNESS_RATING,
           NULL AS FUZZ_LENGTH,
           ROOTSTOCK,
           NULL AS PEEL_THICKNESS
      FROM APPLES
      WHERE pin_Cursor_name = 'apples'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UPPER(pin_Cursor_name) AS FRUIT_TYPE,
           VARIETY_NAME,
           COLOR,
           SIZE,
           NULL AS TARTNESS_RATING,
           FUZZ_LENGTH,
           NULL AS ROOTSTOCK,
           NULL AS PEEL_THICKNESS
      FROM PEACHES
      WHERE pin_Cursor_name = 'peaches'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UPPER(pin_Cursor_name) AS FRUIT_TYPE,
           VARIETY_NAME,
           COLOR,
           SIZE,
           NULL AS TARTNESS_RATING,
           NULL AS FUZZ_LENGTH,
           NULL AS ROOTSTOCK,
           PEEL_THICKNESS
      FROM KUMQUATS
      WHERE pin_Cursor_name = 'kumquats'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UPPER(pin_Cursor_name) AS FRUIT_TYPE,
           VARIETY_NAME,
           'GREEN' AS COLOR,
           SIZE,
           NULL AS TARTNESS_RATING,
           FUZZ_LENGTH,
           ROOTSTOCK,
           NULL AS PEEL_THICKNESS
      FROM KIWIS
      WHERE pin_Cursor_name = 'kiwis';
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN csrFruits LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pin_Cursor_name || ' - ' ||
                         aRow.VARIETY_NAME || ', ' ||
                         aRow.COLOR || ', ' ||
                         aRow.SIZE);
  END LOOP;
END DO_SOMETHING;
```

So here we have a cursor which will read from one of four different tables (APPLES, PEACHES, KUMQUATS, and KIWIS) depending on the input parameter. The idea is to have each of the subqueries return a rowset of the same "shape", adding `NULL AS XXX` for each column which an individual subquery doesn't supply.

Best of luck.

Comment: There is some merit to this approach. I'm working with more than a few constraints that might make this difficult though. I don't think anyone else is going to dare to answer, and this is actually a good answer for the more general case... so I'm accepting it. Thanks for the luck, I'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem statement is quite a bit vague and it's unclear for me what constraints you have and what that "other system" expects as a return value. You also might have an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so the answer by @bobjarvis might have a valid point too.

The key problem here is that in PL/SQL there is no way to convert an [explicit cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS99956) to a [cursor variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00605). Thus the following "simple" solution is not possible:

```
-- pseudo PL/SQL code
cursor cur_a ...
cursor cur_b ...

function get_cursor(p_cur_name varchar2) return sys_refcursor is 
  v_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  execute immediate 'open v_cur for p_cur_name';
  return v_cur;
end;

v_cur := get_cursor('cur_b');
```

In the example package below I assume that all the cursors will have the same result set structure. I was lazy and used weak cursor variables even I should have used strong ones. The package code should be easy to follow.

There is at least one other variation that might be useful for you - bulk collect the data to a collection and process the collection with other subroutines. Below `print(varchar2)` just demonstrates how to open-iterate-close a cursor "dynamically" with a `dbms_output.put_line`.

```
create or replace package so48 is
  cursor cur_a is
    select 'A1' as val, 1 as id from dual union all
    select 'A2' as val, 2 as id from dual union all
    select 'A3' as val, 3 as id from dual
  ;
  cursor cur_b is
    select 'B1' as val, 4 as id from dual union all
    select 'B2' as val, 5 as id from dual union all
    select 'B3' as val, 6 as id from dual
  ;

  function get_cursor(p_cur_name in varchar2) return sys_refcursor;
  procedure print(p_cur in sys_refcursor);

  procedure print(p_cur_name in varchar2);
end;
/
show errors

create or replace package body so48 is
  function get_cursor(p_cur_name in varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
    v_cur sys_refcursor;
  begin
    case 
      when p_cur_name = 'A' then
        open v_cur for
          select 'A1' as val, 1 as id from dual union all
          select 'A2' as val, 2 as id from dual union all
          select 'A3' as val, 3 as id from dual
        ;
      when p_cur_name = 'B' then
        open v_cur for
          select 'B1' as val, 4 as id from dual union all
          select 'B2' as val, 5 as id from dual union all
          select 'B3' as val, 6 as id from dual
        ;
      else
        null;
    end case;

    return v_cur;
  end;

  procedure print(p_cur in sys_refcursor) is
    v_val varchar2(32767);
    v_id number;
  begin
    loop
      fetch p_cur into v_val, v_id;
      exit when p_cur%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line('(val = ' || v_val || ')(id = ' || v_id || ')');
    end loop;
  end;

  procedure print(p_cur_name in varchar2) is
    plsql_compilation_error exception;
    pragma exception_init(plsql_compilation_error, -6550);
    v_cur_name constant varchar2(32767) := 'so48.' || p_cur_name;
    v_plsql constant varchar2(32767) :=
      q'[declare
        v_val varchar2(32767);
        v_id number;
      begin
        open ]' || v_cur_name || q'[;
        loop
          fetch ]' || v_cur_name || q'[ into v_val, v_id;
          exit when ]' || v_cur_name || q'[%notfound;
          dbms_output.put_line('(val = ' || v_val || ')(id = ' || v_id || ')');
        end loop;
        close ]' || v_cur_name || q'[;
      end;]';
  begin
    execute immediate v_plsql;
  exception
    when plsql_compilation_error then
      dbms_output.put_line('PL/SQL compilation error');
  end;
end;
/
show errors
```

**Example run**

```
SQL> exec so48.print(so48.get_cursor('A'))
(val = A1)(id = 1)
(val = A2)(id = 2)
(val = A3)(id = 3)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec so48.print('cur_b')
(val = B1)(id = 4)
(val = B2)(id = 5)
(val = B3)(id = 6)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I forgot mention explictly the explicit cursors have to be in package's public interface so that the cursor is visible for SQL-engine in `execute immediate`.